# How to get the compiled method the is being executed

Tags: reflection, pharo

How to get an instance of *CompiledMethod* that is currently being executed?

i.e.

```
someMethod
  | thisMethod |
  thisMethod := "here I want to access an instance of _CompiledMethod_ that refers to #someMethod".
  ^ thisMethod selector
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method that is currently being executed can be retrieved by `#method` message from current context, which can be accessed through `thisContext` pseudo variable.

This way example code will look like this:

```
someMethod
  | thisMethod |
  thisMethod := thisContext method.
  ^ thisMethod selector
```