# smalltalk reflection - how to get method name?

Tags: oop, reflection, smalltalk, visual-age

Assume I have a class and an instance method:

```
 ClassExample#methodExample
      ^"???"
```

Is there any way in Smalltalk to get the name of the method:

```
 var := ClassExample new.
 nameOfMyMethod := var methodExample.
 "nameOfMyMethod should be 'methodExample' (a string or symbol)"
```

?

I'm developing in VisualAge. Thanks for help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738561/how-to-get-the-compiled-method-the-is-being-executed

Comment: The above link is for Pharo.  VA Smalltalk doesn't have thisContext.

Comment: Possibly a more important question is if this is really what you want to do. Writing code that will break under a rename refactoring isn't necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
methodExample
    ^(Processor activeProcess stackAtFrame: 0 offset: -9) selector
```